# SQLAlchemy-like relationships without SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy gives me nice relationships between objects.
When I change one object's member, it's automatically added to the other object's list, etc.
However - I don't want to use a DB. I'd like to keep my objects in the memory.
Is there a module that gives this kind of behavior without using SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the full context of the project that you are working on, but you can use SQLAlchemy to a sqlite database or even easier hold everything in memory. The only issue if you hold things in memory is that once you restart your process you will lose all the data.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#connecting

Comment: That's a possible solution, but what if I just want to have normal objects, without the need to deal with any kind of DB?

Comment: @AviadNissel so you want an ORM without a database? How a about a class? Relationships are easy as well: Assign them on instances as lists, just like with SQLAlchemy. If you want query behaviour to retrieve objects, then you want a database.

Comment: A normal class would work fine for those situations, but if you want any kind of persistence then it would be a good idea to use some sort of ORM.